# How to move plt.axhline

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot that my code is generating, example below:

[image]

I am trying to find a way in which I can freely move the red line across the axis so it slides up and down, but so far I haven't found any guidance on how to do that, any advise would be appreciated, the code that generates the figure is below:

```
plt.figure()
plt.axhline(y = frame_threshold, color = 'r', linestyle = '-')
plt.plot(framenumber, Avfiltered)
```

Comment: I think you're looking for something along the lines a [matplotlib slider](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/slider_demo.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, the horizontal line is represented by x-values 0 and 1 and both corresponding y-values set to the given y-value. A ["y axis transform"](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_yaxis_transform.html) is used to tell that x should be interpreted as "axis coordinates", and y as "data coordinates". The [matplotlib tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) contains more information about coordinates and transforms.

You can update the y-data of the horizontal line to have it at another position. The following example code uses a click event to demonstrate such an update.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def on_click(event):
     global hor_line
     if event.inaxes:
          # hor_line.set_data(([0, 1], [event.ydata, event.ydata]))
          hor_line.set_ydata([event.ydata] * 2)
          plt.draw()

frame_threshold = 5

plt.figure()
hor_line = plt.axhline(y=frame_threshold, color='r', linestyle='-')
plt.plot(np.arange(200), np.random.normal(0.1, 1, 200).cumsum())

plt.connect('button_press_event', on_click)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to implement a draggable line already, but I had the problem of it being too short (more like a dot), could you point me to where in your code you specify that the red line should cover the entire x axis

Comment: If you create the line via `axhline(y, xmin, xmax)` leaving `xmin` and `xmax` to their default values of `0` and `1`, the line will cover the complete width of the plot (see [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html)).   You can also explicitly call `hor_line.set_data(([0, 1], [..., ...]))` to make sure the line goes from the left (`0` in "axis coordinates"), to the right of the plot (`1` in "axis coordinates").